# How to make an ad responsive

Tags: html, css

This is my website: http://thelolinternet.com/

As you can see, there is an ad upside of the size `height="90" width="728"`
but when you open the website in mobile (try changing the browser width), the ad's size does not get decreased. What is the solution?

I do not know how to make it responsive.

This is the code:

```
<div  data-WRID="WRID-147582892358590272" data-widgetType="Push Content"  data-class="affiliateAdsByFlipkart" height="90" width="728"></div>
<script async src="//affiliate.flipkart.com/affiliate/widgets/FKAffiliateWidgets.js"></script>
```

And here is my code after the percentage suggestion:

```
<div data-WRID="WRID-147582892358590272" data-widgetType="Push Content" data-class="affiliateAdsByFlipkart" height="6.181318681318681%" width="50%"></div>
<script async src="//affiliate.flipkart.com/affiliate/widgets/FKAffiliateW‌​idgets.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use percentages instead of explicit pixel dimensions

Comment: And use these percentages in CSS since width/height get deprecated http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_width.asp

Comment: @Xenos that's tables, not `div`. OP is using `div`

Comment: No, it is not working. It is not making it responsive...Wait let me provide screenshot.

Comment: @Davidbot Things aren't just made responsive. Percentage widths fit to the container. Maybe you need to use media queries. Can't help properly with the little information you provide

Comment: Check out this screenshot : http://i.imgur.com/hH3NNky.png
this is what happened, when i changed it to percentage

Also, i do not have a CSS option in wordpress. I need to put @media in html, how to do it?

Comment: Google on how to use media queries to alter layouts. Still can't help you. Put the code here that you tried after I suggested percent widths

Comment: `<div  data-WRID="WRID-147582892358590272" data-widgetType="Push Content"  data-class="affiliateAdsByFlipkart" height="6.181318681318681%" width="50%"></div><script async src="//affiliate.flipkart.com/affiliate/widgets/FKAffiliateWidgets.js"></script>`

Comment: So what isn't working?

Comment: @AndyHolmes Same applies for div: `width` is nowhere to be found in the WHATWG living spec https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-div-element

Comment: Ok, this is the solution to my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683626/make-banner-ads-responsive

But wordpress is not providing me option to add CSS file , what to do?

Comment: Create it and upload it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this, test it out in your dev environment because it will not work in fiddle

```js
device_width = window.outerWidth;
ad = document.getElementById('ad');

if (device_width == '740')
{
  ad.style.width = '700'
}
else if(device_width == '480')
{
  ad.style.width = '400'
}
```

```html
<div id="ad">
  <h2>THIS IS AN AD</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not responsive :/
I think this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1r1kydjz/10/) is the solution. But how ot apply it without using CSS File

Comment: you can use js file

Comment: how, i am new, sorry.

Comment: let me change my answer

Comment: ok I finished writing it, by the way is the website for a client?

Comment: No, it is my website, i will work on it. Where is the edited code mate?

Comment: its there dude, I just edited my last code, refresh ur browser

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It is still not responsive. Neither in your snippet code

Comment: do u skype, maybe I can help u better in person