# How to make modern flipkart banner responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have a situation where I want to make flipkart banner responsive.

It will work fine for screen sizes more than 768px, but it does not work for mobile sizes.

I have tried this thread [Make banner ads responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683626/make-banner-ads-responsive) but it is only working for older banner not for new banner.

**DEMO HERE:** https://jsfiddle.net/hwub8sw1/

[image]

Here is what i have tried:

**style.css**

```
* {margin:0; padding:0;}

div[data-wrid^=WRID] {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:100% !important;
}

div[data-wrid^=WRID] img {
  max-width:100% !important;
  margin:0 auto;
}

iframe {
  max-width:730px !important;
     text-align:center !important;
     margin:0 auto;
}

@media (max-width:730px) {
    iframe {
      max-width:100% !important;
    }

     div[data-wrid^=WRID] img {
      max-width:100% !important;
      margin:0 auto;
    }   
} 


@media (max-width:400px) {
    iframe {
      max-width:100% !important;
    }

     div[data-wrid^=WRID] img {
      max-width:90% !important;
      margin:0 auto;   
    }             
}   


@media (min-width:320px) {     
    iframe {
      max-width:100% !important;
    }

     div[data-wrid^=WRID] img {
      max-width:90% !important;    
      margin:0 auto;
    }/* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ 
}

@media (min-width:481px) { 
      iframe {
      max-width:100% !important;
    }

     div[data-wrid^=WRID] img {
      max-width:100% !important;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
/* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ 
}
@media (min-width:641px) { 

      iframe {
      max-width:100% !important;
    }

     div[data-wrid^=WRID] img {
      max-width:100% !important;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
/* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ 
}
```

**html**

```
 <div data-wrid="WRID-149802169852992393" data-widgettype="staticBanner" data-responsive="yes" data-class="affiliateAdsByFlipkart" height="90" width="728" style="text-align:center;"></div>
      <script async src="//affiliate.flipkart.com/affiliate/widgets/FKAffiliateWidgets.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have locked this question because [you have been repeatedly abusing the edit system](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45563424/revisions) to edit in and then remove nonsense. That line doesn't belong in questions *at all*, and I suspect you know that. You *certainly* shouldn't be repeatedly adding and removing it in an attempt to "bump" your question. This is an abuse of our system, and very annoying to other users.

Comment: You did the same thing on [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501261/tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-statuscode-302), too, but no one caught you, so you're getting off with a warning this time. The next time we catch you doing this, it will come with a suspension attached.

Answer (score 1):

What is the width of the banner it's taking? You're having `!important` for every max-width statement, which is really not a good practice. 
Try removing `max-width:730px !important;` . I think for every instance its taking this, as its not under any `min:` or `max:` criteria and has an `!important` tag attached to it

Answer (score 0):

Using script you are loading flipkart banner on your page inside an `iframe`. And you can't apply any custom `css` or `script` to any `iframe` coming from other than your domain. For more refer existing answers: [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe][1])